# Unknown pattern letter: T - Parse string date with pattern T to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, localdate, date

I need to parse the following date format in String to Java `LocalDateTime`.

So I get date as String like this: `2019-09-20T12:36:39.359`

I have the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void testDateTime() {
    assertEquals(SomeObject.getLocalDate(), LocalDateTime.parse(“2019-09-20T12:36:39.359”, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS")));
}
```

The unit test fails with exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: T

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parsePattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1661)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1570)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateTimeFormatter.java:536)
```

How can I correctly parse the date in this format to `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: you can escape the T with single quotes: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS"

Comment: Your string is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, the default for `LocalDateTime`, so you can just leave out the formatter: `LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-20T12:36:39.359")`. The parsed `LocalDateTime` object won’t ever be equal to a `String`, though.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use  `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` as below

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());

    String dateStr = "2019-09-20T12:36:39.359";

    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, dtf);
```

Comment: No need to specify a formatting pattern. This input is in standard ISO 8601 format used by default when parsing/generating text. `LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-09-20T12:36:39.359" )`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` as the formatter:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-20T12:36:39.359", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: How can we get the nanosecond to be exact and strip out the 0s `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2019-09-20T12:36:39.359
Actual   :2019-09-20T12:36:39.000000359`

Comment: @M06H Here you are comparing two `String` values. You can easily strip the `0`s from the `String`.

Comment: Ok and how about if it is localdatetime I compare instead of string?

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a `String` with a `Date`, that will say you they are not equals.

You don't even need to write the `DateTimeFormatter`.

Writing this code would be enough:

```
assertEquals("2019-09-20T12:36:39.359", LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-20T12:36:39.359").toString());
```

Comment: The default `DateTimeFormatter` is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.